# How can I expand the width of the wheel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying for hours to change the width of the wheel and items, but I cant figure out how to https://jsfiddle.net/ywm3zbc4/105/

I want to change the wheel width to 600px and still use the function to choose where the wheel should land

```
    .wheel {
      width: 600px;
    }

    var wheel = new SpinWheel(20);
```

Without it breaking compleatly, when running it after changing the width it skips over and doesnt land on "20"

Comment: what width do you want? 470? what do you mean breaking it completely it seems to work please explain yourself more.

Comment: If you edit the width of the wheel and then run the function to land on e.x 20
Example:    var wheel = new SpinWheel(20);
 it wont land on 20 it breaks the function
http://prntscr.com/lep0fe

Comment: well it does for me? the width shouldnt affect it as its centered, did you write this code or get it from somewhere else?

Comment: If you change the width of the wheel to example 600px

And then change var wheel = new SpinWheel(resultID);
To var wheel = new SpinWheel(20);

It should land on 20 but doesnt becouse the width was increased
http://prntscr.com/lep25c

Comment: so you want it responsive because it seems in your post you just want the width to be 470? please edit your post to be what you want, what you expected, and what acutally happened, and reasons why you think it happened or reasons why you know it wont work.

Comment: Alright, I edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

As Inside `wheel-wrapper` class you have (39 wheel-items) `wheel-item`. you need to change width at both places `wheel-wrapper` and `wheel-item`. you need to divide `wheel-wrapper` by `wheel-item` you supposed to want. for example, I have took `2925px` width of `wheel-wrapper` and you had `39` items. As per this, wheel-item's width `75px`.

Note: you can change it as per your requirements.

Changes I have made:

```
.wheel {
  width: 470px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px 9px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  &-wrapper {
    width: 2925px;   //changed
  }
  &-item {
    float: left; 
    width: 75px;    //changed
    height: 30px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    p {
      line-height: 30px;
      margin: 0;
    }
  }
```

[Test link](https://jsfiddle.net/nisarg1792/ywm3zbc4/104/)

Comment: Scroll down on the script and change
    var wheel = new SpinWheel(resultId);
to var wheel = new SpinWheel(20);          Even though it should land on 20 it doesnt